# Script to copy files to azure blob storage without key

Tags: powershell, azure, blob, storage

Is there a way to copy local files to an azure account without the subscription string or account key/pass, but the powershell script would be run in an environment which has access to the account. I know it can be done if the account key is provided but I'm not allowed access to the password.

Comment: Based on my knowledge, I don't think you could do it. This is unsafe behavior.

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by `but the powershell script would be run in an environment which has access to the account`?

Comment: Isn't this possible using SAS token? This way without key or password you would be able to upload it.